# Rails Devise limit user sign up per ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to limit user sign up per IP to 3!
In User model I have:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  validate :validate_ip
  def validate_ip
    errors[:username] << "My error description" if User.where(last_sign_in_ip: last_sign_in_ip).count > 3
  end
end
```

I do know the problem in this line `User.where(last_sign_in_ip: last_sign_in_ip)`
 "last_sign_in_ip" is empty. That's why my condition doesn't work. I need somehow get IP address of user inside the model.

Any advice how I can achieve it?

Comment: So what problem are you seeing?  Is there an error or exception?

Comment: This approach is correct. Explain the issue you are facing. https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

Comment: Question is updated

Comment: try `current_sign_in_ip`

Comment: "current_sign_in_ip" is empty too

Comment: @IgorTikhonenko - did this answer work for you? i am trying to implement something similar

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ip variable from controller. Model cannot access request variables and on signup devise do not update `last_sign_in_ip` or `last_sign_in_ip` so they are null. They are set up only on login.

In your controller before creating the user object pass the ip value as instance variable

```
@remote_ip = request.remote_ip
```

And then in your model use the code below:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  validate :validate_ip
  def validate_ip
    errors[:username] << "My error description" if check_multiple_sign_ups
  end

  def check_multiple_sign_ups
    recent_user_count = User.where(last_sign_in_ip: @remote_ip ).count
    (recent_user_count > 3 ) ? false : true
  end
end
```

Hope this Helps...